# Адресация по объектам BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Пищу парсер на Python 2.7, используя BeautifulSoup 4. Возникла трудность.

Извлек я все элементы `<img ... />` со страницы.

```
for p in allPosts:
    postIMG = p.find_all('img')
```

В итоге получилось:

```
<img alt="Название" data-lazy="https://site.com/a/1.jpg" itemprop="image" 
    src="/static/assets/i/common/no-image/160x90.png"/>
<img alt="Название 2" data-lazy="https://site.com/a/2.jpg" itemprop="image"
    src="/static/assets/i/common/no-image/160x90.png"/>
```

1. Как обратится к тексту? Можно как-то через точку? `postIMG.alt` ? Или как лучше?
2. Как красивее всего извлечь урл картинки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find_all` возвращает список  объектов класса `bs4.element.Tag` и к аттрибутам элемента можно обратиться через словарь `attrs`:

```
for p in allPosts:
    postIMG = p.find_all('img')
    print postIMG[0].attrs['alt']
    print postIMG[0].attrs['src']
```

Если картинка в посте одна, то удобнее использовать метод `find`, вместо `find_all`:

```
for p in allPosts:
    postIMG = p.find('img')
    print postIMG.attrs['alt']
    print postIMG.attrs['src']
```